# Name of YA anthology book from late 80s about Time Travel

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

When I was young I used to check out a book from my local Texas library. It was an anthology of Time Travel stories. It was on the thin size, hard cover and was illustrated. It was in the YA section. It seemed to be brand new and published around the late 80s. The story that I remember the most is about a group of scientists that invent a machine that can peer back through time. They use it to watch Isaac Newton who then becomes paranoid and loses his mind. The pictures from that particular story that I remember are of the scientist watching Newton at work on a small tv screen and another one of Newton sitting in an insane asylum.  I've done some google searches before but haven't turned up anything yet.

Anyone know what this is?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! You have a nice start here but can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in anymore details you may remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of the anthology [*Time Warps*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?284414) edited by [Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov), [Martin H. Greenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_H._Greenberg), and [Charles G. Waugh](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?7778); hardcover, 48 pages, illustrated, published in 1984.

[image: Cover of "Time Warps", showing three men in white suits, with a blackboard visible in the background. One of the men is reaching towards a gold-colored object.]

The story you remember is ["The Biography Project"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?973606) by [H. L. Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._L._Gold), first published (as by "Dudley Dell") in [*Galaxy Science Fiction*, September 1951](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58654+c), which is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v02n06_1951-09#page/n159/mode/2up). Here is the [ISFDB synopsis](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?973606):

> The scientists of an institute devoted to filming great figures of the past through a time viewer begin with Sir Isaac Newton, but quickly realize that the project must be abandoned.

Comment: Yes! That is the one. I remember the cover of it now. Thank you soooo much!!